# OrderBY On model relationship eloquant on controller?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am not able to find any perfect solution for it.

Controller:

```
 $servicerequest = ServiceRequest::selectRaw('count(id) as totalservice,max(created_date) as last_service,service_provider_id,id,service_id,account_id,service_request,created_date')->with(['account' => function($first) use ($keyword) {
                        $first->select('id', 'restaurant_name')->orderBy('restaurant_name', 'DESC');
                    }])
                ->with(['serviceProvider' => function($query) use ($keyword) {
                        $query->select('id', 'company_name');
                    }])->groupBy('account_id')
                ->orderBy('company_name', 'DESC')
                ->paginate(100);
```

I need an order by on model relation table field and that effect on main table data. because it's and one to one relationship so no need to order by on the inside.

Like I need to the orderby whole on relations data.

Collection:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You must make join your relation table to used orderBy relation table.

You can try this code.

```
$servicerequest = ServiceRequest::selectRaw('count(id) as totalservice, max(created_date) as last_service,service_provider_id,id,service_id,account_id,service_request,created_date, SERVICEPROVIDERTABLE.company_name')
                                        ->join('serviceProvider', 'SERVICEPROVIDERTABLE.id', '=', 'SERVICEREQUESTTABLE.service_provider_id')
                                        ->with([
                                            'account' => function ($first) use ($keyword) {
                                                $first->select('id', 'restaurant_name')
                                                      ->orderBy('restaurant_name', 'DESC');
                                            }
                                        ])
                                        //->with([
                                        //    'serviceProvider' => function ($query) use ($keyword) {
                                        //        $query->select('id', 'company_name');
                                        //    }
                                        //])
                                        ->groupBy('account_id')
                                        ->orderBy('SERVICEPROVIDERTABLE.company_name', 'DESC')
                                        ->paginate(100);
```

i hope this works.

Comment: Thanks ! But this is not way.. i ask for the solution in same not for the different way. i already know in join we can do it. but if know about laravel or ORM then have you any idea then post it. 
Is this your answer for reputation gain then sorry i can't :) ?

Comment: Don't worry for that, i'am not come for reputation, but come for get the problem and i can help to resolve that. i think in laravel cannot do that, because i'am already have a problem like yours.

Comment: So you say there is not any solution for it. i have to necessary use join for it ?

Comment: As i know is not have solution for that. Maybe others person have that. 
I'm waiting for this answer too :D